# как завершить процесс nohup?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Запустил следующей командой: `nohup python3 /home/python_ml/BotMainPart.py`
Как мне остановить выполнение данного процесса?

Comment: по классике - кильнуть.  узнайте его pid и пошлите ему `kill <pid>`, возможно, нужно послать "правильный сигнал" - тогда `kill -9 <pid>`, но процесс должен уметь правильно отработать этот сигнал.

Comment: а как узнать его pid?

Comment: в списке процессов.

Comment: узнать список процессов можно в top/htop/atop, также запустив `pgrep python3` или `ps aux | grep python3` и потом глазками найти нужный процесс.

Comment: Обычно, программисты в своем коде сохраняют свой pid  специальный файл (например в /var/run или /tmp) и задача прибить процесс стает тривиальной.

Comment: просто ubuntu server для меня штука неизведанная

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы использовал: `killall python3`

Comment: Не лучшая идея. Это убъёт все процессы запущенные python3. Лучше что-то вроде такого:
kill $(ps aux | grep BotMainPart.py | awk '{ print $2 }')